# Change the location of a listing on Tripadvisor

Tags: tripadvisor

I have noticed that of the six budget accommodations I know to exist in the Bondi area of Sydney Australia that only two are listed under "Bondi" and the other four are under "Sydney".

This is just a concrete example of something which must occur in many places. I am wondering if there is some way provided in Tripadvisor.com to advise them to list places in the correct place.

So far I can't find it on the site or by searching on Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much hunting and Googling I found the answer on tripadvisor's site:

[**How to alert us when a listing is incorrect**](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/help/how_to_alert_us_when_a_listing_is_incorrect)

> If you are a TripAdvisor member and you notice that a hotel or attraction listing is **in the wrong town** or pinned incorrectly on the map, you'll need to [e-mail us](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Support?topic=how_to_alert_us_when_a_listing_is_incorrect).

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>